# Rails 3 ActionMailer error - hostname was not match with the server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am setting up SMTP for my Rails 3 App.

This configuration works.

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "mydomain.com",  
  :user_name            => "<username>",  
  :password             => "<password>",  
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

But this configuration doesn't.
It gives "hostname was not match with the server certificate"

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "some_other_server.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "mydomain.com",  
  :user_name            => "<username>",  
  :password             => "<password>",  
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

Strangely, the same configuration works in Rails 2.3.8. (:tls => true)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this in your ActionMailer smtp settings:

```
:openssl_verify_mode => 'none'
```

It gives you a secure connection, but doesn't verify things.  Might not be the best idea for a production app, but it works for me.

Comment: It's actually a bad idea for a production app,

Comment: A: Hello I have problem with my door lock; B: Try to remove door or just keep it open; A: Works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 17):

I had the exact same problem. Solved it by changing ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings:

```
:enable_starttls_auto => true
```

to

```
:enable_starttls_auto => false
```

and had to make sure :user_name value included the @domain.com

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me. It gives another error like 'You must starttls first' or something like that.

Comment: Wow, I can't imagine a more vague response. You didn't say where to put those statements, not even a file name.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed to get my mail sending from a Network Solutions domain smtp server. Although the accepted answer also worked, this one seems like the better long-term solution

Comment: With sendgrid there was no need to include @domain.com in `:user_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supplying a default address in your mailer (located in app/mailers)? The last time I recall having this problem, the hostname in my mailer didn't match the hostname in my smtp settings.

Comment: No, there's no default address in the mailer.