# mail gem SSL_read:: wrong version number when trying to connect to Exchange 2003 IMAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

Its very late & I'm very tired but will provide more details later.

Problem: Testing ruby Mail gem doing IMAP stuff against GMail, Yahoo & Exchange 2003.
GMail is good.
Yahoo is good.
Exchange 2003 causes '''SSL_read:: wrong version number'''
Response to '''openssl s_client -crlf -connect myimapserver:imaps''' is;

```
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2914 bytes and written 509 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: A8180000B48B14E0FB6FEBC0666C72BCB03A96489A5A6865C76ABCB3E55585FE
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key:      3C6B487D9BB2AD63928A78EAD57B305864D23A8C196D1D1D5414979E78B5D0B1E939B5F257EEFAA6D27E14FAC6AD23CE
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1360581090
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    ---
    * OK Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 IMAP4rev1 server version 6.5.7638.1  (WDCPOST.waitomo-int.govt.nz) ready.
```

Unsecured IMAP works but SSL does not
Mail gem configured for port 993 & SSL = true.

Any ideas? I have been hunting for hours now without finding a reference.

Comment: Strugling with the same problem, hotmail in my case. Have you found any answer?

Answer (score 0):

:openssl_verify_mode => 'none' may not be ideal, but might work for you.
check it out here:
[Rails 3 ActionMailer error - hostname was not match with the server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021416/rails-3-actionmailer-error-hostname-was-not-match-with-the-server-certificate)