# Redmine actionmailer ssl failure

Tags: actionmailer, redmine

I recently upgraded Redmine from 2.2.x to 2.3.0. At first it looked like the upgrade was smooth and successful, but my manager noticed that she wasn't getting any emails after the upgrade. I tried sending a test email from the email settings page and get the following error:

```
An error occurred while sending mail (uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_OPENSSL)
```

gem
From my configuration.yml

```
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: '192.168.10.211'
      port: 25
      domain: 'mydomain.com'
      openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

We have a local mail relay that is open to the internal network, and this configuration worked fine with the previous version of Redmine. I have verified that I can reach the server and can send email through telnet, so the relay is accepting email from the server. The issue seems to be in Redmine / ruby.

Misc details that might be helpful:

```
Ruby 1.8.7
RubyGems 1.8.25
actionmailer (3.2.13, 3.2.11)
```

*disclaimer: I am a PHP guy, so if you need more info just lemme know and I will try to track it down.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue after some playing around with the configuration settings and reading [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021416/rails-3-actionmailer-error-hostname-was-not-match-with-the-server-certificate).

I ended up with this:

```
# default configuration options for all environments
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: '192.168.10.211'
      port: 25
      domain: 'mydomain.com'
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      #openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
```

From my config above I commented out openssl_verify_mode and added the enable_starttls_auto set to false. This seems to have gotten me back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked when I used both 
`enable_starttls_auto: false` and `openssl_verify_mode: 'none'` together.